# Do they state how much money Scott Pilgrim earns in the movie?

Tags: scott-pilgrim

In the comics its pretty clear how much Scott Earns per fight when battling the League of Evil Exes. But in the movies its just coins on screen.

Is there a definite answer as to how much Scott earns by the end of the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Scott Pilgrim Wikia](http://scottpilgrim.wikia.com/wiki/Coins_and_Rewards), Scott earns $7,777,777 for fighting and defeating the final boss in the film Scott Pilgrim vs The World. He also wins a negligible amount of money (between $2 and $20) for defeating each of the other bosses.

In the Scott Pilgrim game, he wins around $200